# Diferencia entre Task y Thread C#

Tags: c#, .net

Alguien sería tan amable de explicar cual es la diferencia entre Task y Thread en C# y algunos de sus de metodos, la información que encuentro suele ser algo ambigua y confusa.

Quiero implementar un método que compruebe datos de una API REST y que lo haga con un bucle infinito con pausas y en otro método que vaya haciendo pausas de unos 2 segundos para pasar a la siguiente línea de código o llamar algún método.

Comment: La verdad que es una buena pregunta, pero implicaria casi contestarte un capitulo entero de un libro (es mas, en C# in depth ES un capitulo entero). Task es un thread. pero es bastante mas complejo que eso. prueba buscando el capitulo de ese libro (que se encuentra gratis)

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Task es la forma de realizar tareas asíncronas desde .Net 4.0 y con mejoras en .Net 4.5. Si utilizas .Net 4.5 no hay razón para seguir utilizando Thread, es mucho más fácil utilizar métodos asíncronos marcados con async.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` es un concepto de menor nivel de abstraccion, generalmente ya no se recomienda trabajar directamente con esta clase, aunque te permite manipular cosas importantes como si el `Thread` corre en segundo plano o primer plano, te permite ademas usar *primitivas de sincronizacion* entre otras tantas cosas.

Ahora bien `Task` y `Task<T>` son un par de clases que traen un mayor nivel de abstracción y son parte de la `TPL (Task Parallel Library)` generalmente esta es la clase que deseas usar para hacer código asíncrono, ya que Task y Task harán el mejor uso posible de todo lo que ofrece .NET para hacer que tu código corra de forma asíncrona/paralela.

Te recomendaría que estudies muy bien la TPL, estudiándola bien te darás cuenta de cuanto trabajo te ahorras al trabajar con `Task` en vez de `Thread`

Revisa el siguiente [libro](https://stephencleary.com/book/).

**EDICIÓN**

Como bien menciona [NaCI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4499/nacl), asincrono y paralelo no significan lo mismo, aclarando los conceptos:

**procesamiento paralelo:** se refiere a repartir el trabajo a realizar en multiples hilos que estén trabajando de forma concurrente(al mismo tiempo)

**procesamiento asíncrono:** se refiere al uso de *callbacks* para minimizar el uso de nuevos threads, esto es, utiliza los threads existentes, en el caso de C# el thread que inicia una llamada asíncrona queda contenido en un contexto de sincronización que entre otras cosas tiene una referencia al thread al que tiene que regresar la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Nótese que Asíncrono != Paralelo.

Comment: Efectivamente, déjame editar las respuesta.